# Is it possible to use a friend function to convert a class-type a basic-type?

Tags: c++, type-conversion

Is it possible using friends?

```
class MyClass
{
private:
    int myInteger;
    float myFloat;

public:
    void SetData(int a, float b)
    {
        myInteger = a;
        myFloat = b;
    }
    operator int();
    friend operator float(MyClass & );
};

MyClass :: operator int()
{
    return myInteger;
}

operator float(MyClass & obj)
{
    return obj.myFloat;
}
```

This code doesn't compile. How to do it in a correct way?

Comment: have you tried it? if so, what's the result?

Comment: Interestingly, the summary table at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators doesn't list this case.  I know several people prefer cppreference.com to cplusplus.com, but I was surprised to see it fell short here.

Comment: I think a conversion function needs to be a member function, see [class.conv.fct] and http://stackoverflow.com/q/2999506/420683

Comment: The declaration should be : `friend operator float(MyClass& obj);`. But I'm even sure if it works.

Comment: @JoeZ cppreference started as the library reference: the core language part is work-in-progress. The page about user-defined conversion functions is still a redlink (it's linked from the page you referenced under the bullet "2)")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VS2008 says:

```
error C2801: 'operator float' must be a non-static member
```

Why not making op float a member?

```
operator float(){ return myFloat;}
```

Comment: I know it can be done with members.

Answer (score 1):

If overloading the operator isn't working for you, consider using a named function:

```
float ToFloat(MyClass & obj)
{
    return obj.myFloat;
}
```

This will also avoid implicit conversions... but I suppose if you were planning on overloading the operator your intention was to allow the implicit conversion.