# Can there be global custom type conversion operators in CLI?

Tags: .net, c++-cli, conversion-operator

I have a native class `Nullable<T>` that is used in a native application that provides the following interface:

```
template <typename T>
class Nullable
{
public:
  //! Check if the value is null
  bool IsNull() const;
  //! Retrieve the current value (or default when IsNull is true)
  const T& Get() const;
  //! Set a value (IsNull will become false)
  void Set(const T& value);
};
```

For select types that I actually use with `Nullable`, I'd like to use custom conversion. Such operator would be a syntax sugar for:

```
System::Int32^ NullableToInt32(const Nullable<int>& value) 
{
 return value.IsNull() ? nullptr : gcnew System::Int32(value.Get()); 
}
```

However the following gives me an error:

```
operator System::Int32^ (const Nullable<int>& value) 
{
 return value.IsNull() ? nullptr : gcnew System::Int32(value.Get());
}
```

The error is:

```
nullableutil.h(7): error C2801: 'operator System::Int32 ^' must be a non-static member
```

I cannot add that operator in `Nullable` because it's a pure native class. I don't want to write a CLI wrapper around it. I'd just like to define these operators because conversions between C# types and `Nullable` will be quite common in the code I'm gonna write.

Is there a way to have a conversion operator between managed and native types?

Comment: The conversion operators in C++ need to be member functions, you cannot work around this. See e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999506/non-member-conversion-functions-casting-different-types-e-g-directx-vector-to). This is also true for C#, so you cannot introduce custom conversion e.g. from `Int32` to `Int16`.

Comment: @dymanoid Damn, I completely forgot about that (since some other operators nay be global). Maybe someone can come up with a partial solution? C# has class extensions.

Comment: What do you mean by "class extensions in C#"? Do you mean extension methods? They won't allow you to define (static) conversion operators, too.

Comment: The .NET rules for conversion operators are strict, they must be static methods without an argument that convert to the type of the class that embeds them.  Since Int32^ is entirely too ugly to contemplate, you have a reason to re-implement System::Nullable.